# An input element for Identification Numbers (ID)

Tags: html, css

I am helping to develop a web application, and the web application will require an ID number. I am trying to separate a single input field into thirteen blocks, using a background image, and letter-spacing.

As you can probably guess, I am having difficulty with this. I got the box kind of okay, but a fourteenth box keeps on appearing as the screen reduces. I am also having trouble with letter-spacing as it does not accept percentages.

Does anyone know of a good way to create an ID box like I have described, preferably without the use of other programming languages aside from HTML and CSS, but if that is impossible, that is also fine.

The code below is my CSS

```
#right3 input {
    background-image: url(blocks.jpg);
    background-size: 7.229307692%;
    letter-spacing: 7.229307692%
}
```

Comment: Could you add your HTML, and ideally make a snippet or demo, thanks

Comment: use px; instead of %;

Answer (score 0):

As i understood, you missed background `no-repeat` option.
See manual [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-repeat.asp).
You may use fixed dimensions values for the blocks or background, text offsets(padding, margin). For everything to be aligned perfectly.

Comment: It just occured to me to make a background with only thirteen blocks and use the no repeat option then. SO thanks for reminding me of that, but my letter spacing is a bit of an issue since I need the numbers to always be in their individual blocks, not matter if the screen size.